# content query webpart itemstyle wrapped by group style in XSLT

Tags: xslt, sharepoint-2010

I have the following markup:

```
<ul id="slider">    
    <!-- slider item -->
    <li>
        ...
    </li>
    <!-- end of slider item -->
</ul>
```

and I have defined the following itemStyle and GroupStyle xsl in `header.xsl` and `itemStyle.xsl` for displaying data from a SharePoint 2010 List:

```
<!-- in header.xsl -->
<xsl:template name="Slider" match="*[@GroupStyle='Slider']" mode="header">
    <ul id="slider">
    </ul>
</xsl:template>

<!-- in itemStyle.xsl -->
<xsl:template name="Slider" match="Row[@Style='Slider']" mode="itemstyle">
    <xsl:variable name="SafeImageUrl">
        <xsl:call-template name="OuterTemplate.GetSafeStaticUrl">
            <xsl:with-param name="UrlColumnName" select="@Picture"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="Title">
        <xsl:call-template name="OuterTemplate.GetTitle">
            <xsl:with-param name="Title" select="@Title" />
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="Details">
        <xsl:call-template name="OuterTemplate.GetTitle">
            <xsl:with-param name="Title" select="@Details" />
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:variable>
    <li>
        <img src="{$SafeImageUrl}" alt="{$Title}" />
        <section class="media-description">
            <h2 class="slider-headline"><xsl:value-of  disable-output-escaping="yes" select="$Title" /></h2>
            <p><xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select="$Details" /></p>
        </section>
    </li>
</xsl:template>
```

but the thing is, when applying the previous two templates, the `<ul id="slider"></ul>` appears isolated from all `<li>` items as below:

```
<ul id="slider"></ul>

<!-- a bunch of tables and td here.. -->

<ul style="width: 100%;" class="dfwp-column dfwp-list">
    <li class="dfwp-item"></li>
    <li>
        <img alt="Must-see US exhibitions" src="">
        <section class="media-description"><h2 class="slider-headline">Must-see US exhibitions</h2>
            <p>(Blank)</p>
        </section>
    </li>
    ...
</ul>
```

all I want is to have `<ul id="slider>"` element to wrap those `li's` directly,
so how can i do that ?

Thanks

Comment: Please, don't ask questions for which you don't have the full information. If you don't know what the XML document is, apply the identity transform and it will produce exactly this XML document.

Comment: it is not a full information but its sufficient, see this http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/16284/content-query-webpart-itemstyle-wrapped-by-group-style-in-xslt/16286

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem solved, thanks to [@James Love](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/16284/content-query-webpart-itemstyle-wrapped-by-group-style-in-xslt/16286#16286),

and here are the steps:

- make a copy of ContentQueryMain.xsl, as the following [article](http://panvega.wordpress.com/2009/03/20/sp-cqwp-custom-contentquerymainxsl/) says
- after having a copy of ContentQueryMain.xsl, edit it and look for `OutTemplate.Body`
- then you can place your wrapper in the following variables (but they have to be escaped)

  ```
  <xsl:template name="OuterTemplate.Body">
      <xsl:variable name="BeginColumn1" select="string('&lt;ul id=&quot;slider&quot; class=&quot;dfwp-column dfwp-list&quot; style=&quot;width:')" />
                                                         <!--   ^------------------^   --> 
      <xsl:variable name="BeginColumn2" select="string('%&quot; &gt;')" />
      <xsl:variable name="BeginColumn" select="concat($BeginColumn1, $cbq_columnwidth, $BeginColumn2)" />
      <xsl:variable name="EndColumn" select="string('&lt;/ul&gt;')" />
                                               <!--  ^---------^ -->
  ```

stupid workaround, but its working :S

Answer (score 0):

What's your input XML?

You'd do something like this:

```
<xsl:template name="Slider" match="*[@GroupStyle='Slider']" mode="header"><!-- Sure you want to match *? -->
   <ul id="slider">
     <!-- Match the input XML path to your rows from the context of the matched element above -->
     <xsl:apply-templates select="Row[@Style='Slider']" mode="itemstyle" />
   </ul>
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template name="Slider" match="Row[@Style='Slider']" mode="itemstyle"> 
   <li>..</li>
</xsl:template>
```

Can't figure out why you are using "mode"s either.

Comment: i am using match and mode attributes because this is how SharePoint reads XSLT templates, it is a must!